# Change Google Pie Chart text

Tags: google-visualization

So currently my pie chart looks like https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlucH.png

I would like to change it to "Members" and "Guests", instead of the %

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

sure, if those are the row labels, add this to your [configuration options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#configuration-options)...

`pieSliceText: 'label'`

Comment: Any help thanks, https://stackoverflow.com/q/58993917/11697039 @WhiteHat